# iPhone App Store how to display a long app name with line breaks?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I noticed that some Apps in the **App store** have very long names. When the app's sales page is displayed, their **long titles are displayed in smaller font with line breaks, so the entire name fits on the page.**

Let's say I have an app with a long name: App name: keyword1, keyword2 and keyword3"

However, my app name is displayed as "App name: keywo..." in both the search results and the sales page.

Is there some kind of **an Xcode project setting** that I can use to **tell the app store that my app name is long**? I've seen this done for other apps, but am not sure how to do this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use short and succinct name.